# Elasticsearch migration to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, kibana

I am trying to migrate my `Elasticsearch` data from `elastic.co` to `AWS`.
I have created `S3 bucket` and integrated the `elastic.co` to a `snapshot repository`.
I have created a `snapshot` pointing to the `S3 repository`.
After verifying that the `snapshot` was successfully uploaded to the `S3 bucket`, I have created a new `Elasticsearch` on `AWS`.
I have created a `snapshot repository` with the same `S3 bucket` on the new `Elasticsearch` using the following doc:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/managedomains-snapshots.html

After creating the new `repository`, I verified the connection to the `S3` bucket with the following `API call`:

```
POST /_snapshot/es-s3-demo/_verify
```

I get the `node ids`, which is good.

However, when I am trying to `restore` the `snapshot` from the new `Elasticsearch` on `AWS`, I get the following error:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "Failed to parse object: unknown field [uuid] found",
        "line" : 1,
        "col" : 25
      }
    ],
    "type" : "repository_exception",
    "reason" : "[es-s3-demo] Unexpected exception when loading repository data",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "parsing_exception",
      "reason" : "Failed to parse object: unknown field [uuid] found",
      "line" : 1,
      "col" : 25
    }
  },
  "status" : 500
}
```

I tried to list the `snapshot` with the following `API call`:

```
GET /_cat/snapshots/es-s3-demo
```

and I get the same error.
It looks like `Elasticsearch's` `snapshot repository` is connected to the `S3 bucket` but didn't get any `snapshot` list.

Any suggest?

Comment: I just ran into this as well. Found this blog: https://bonsai.io/blog/migrating-from-elasticsearch-to-opensearch

It mentions that OpenSearch is not able to restore snapshots from Elasticsearch 7.12 and beyond at this time.