# AWS Opensearch - Restore snapshot - Failed to parse object: unknown field [uuid] found

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, snapshot, opensearch, amazon-opensearch

I am currently in the process of migrating data from Elasticsearch 7.17.7 to OpenSearch AWS.

While following the steps outlined in the migration guide provided by AWS (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/migration.html), I have successfully created a snapshot in Elasticsearch version 7.17.7 and uploaded it to an S3 bucket. Additionally, I have successfully registered the repository as shown in the attached image.

However, when attempting to restore the snapshot on AWS, I encountered the following error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "parsing_exception",
                "reason": "Failed to parse object: unknown field [uuid] found",
                "line": 1,
                "col": 25
            }
        ],
        "type": "repository_exception",
        "reason": "[snapshot-temp] Unexpected exception when loading repository data",
        "caused_by": {
            "type": "parsing_exception",
            "reason": "Failed to parse object: unknown field [uuid] found",
            "line": 1,
            "col": 25
        }
    },
    "status": 500
}
```

I tried to list the snapshot and I get the same error.

Please let me know if any clue about this error, how to resolve this.

Thanks

Comment: See comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69443065/12533852): unless something changed since then, your elasticsearch version might not work for this